# Función format para varios datos

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

me gustaría saber cómo puedo escribir con la función format lo siguiente:

La media de arboles en casa es 2

La media de arboles en jardín es 3

La media de arboles en patio es 4

Lo he intentado en el siguiente código:
medias = (2,3,4)

lugares = ("casa", "jardín", "patio")

print("La media de arboles en {} es".format(lugares), medias)

Lo he intentado tambien definiendo un bucle for i in range(lugares) y luego ponerlo en format pero no lo he conseguido.

A ver si me pueden ayudar :(. Gracias a todos.

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a Stackoverflow. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Recuerda agregar todo el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento, y especifica el error que estás obteniendo. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta.

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Hay algo mejor que `format()`: los *f-string*.

Un *f-string* puede contener expresiones Python arbitrarias, encerradas entre corchetes. Las expresiones serán evaluadas y su resultado será insertando dentro del string.

Ejemplo:

```
a = 10
b = 5
print(f"{a} / {b} = {a / b}") # => 10 / 5 = 2.0
```

También tenemos la función básica `zip()`, que toma un dos o más iterables y retorna un iterador que los devuelve como tuplas. En este caso, es una tupla de dos valores `(lugar, media)` que desempacamos inmediantamente en el `for`.

```
print('\n'.join(f"La media de arboles en {lugar} es {media}" for lugar, media in zip(lugares, medias)))
```

La expresión

```
f"La media de arboles en {lugar} es {media}" for lugar, media in zip(lugares, medias)
```

es una expresión generadora: retorna una secuencia de elementos (líneas de impresión) que `join()` toma y une insertando un `\n` entremedio. [Esto no es eficiente; es solo para ilustración]

#### Demo

```
medias = (2, 3, 4)
lugares = ("casa", "jardín", "patio")

print('\n'.join(f"La media de arboles en {lugar} es {media}" for lugar, media in zip(lugares, medias)))
```

produce

```
La media de arboles en casa es 2
La media de arboles en jardín es 3
La media de arboles en patio es 4

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Yo te recomendaría utilizar los `f-string` como comentó @CandidMoe, pero si por cualquier razón lo quisieras hacer con `format` te dejo un ejemplo:

```
medias = (2, 3, 4)

lugares = ("casa", "jardín", "patio")

print(*['La media de árboles en {} es {}'.format(lugar, media) for lugar, media in zip(lugares,medias)], sep = '\n')
```

Vamos a utilizar `zip` para crear el iterador `(lugar, media)` y una comprensión de listas para obtener el lugar y la media.

Utilizamos el asterisco `*` para desempaquetar los elementos de la lista generada por la comprensión de listas

Y por último, se utiliza el argumento `sep` de `print` para indicar el tipo de separador entre cada elemento de la lista

El código anterior imprime lo siguiente:

```
La media de árboles en casa es 2
La media de árboles en jardín es 3
La media de árboles en patio es 4
```